# android - Storage Access Framework - Google Cloud - Failed to save document -KitKat 4.4

Tags: android

I am new to android.
I set up an intent to write to the Google drive:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "newfile.txt");
    startActivityForResult(intent, WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

I get to the "storage picker", i make it to "save to". Then select "google drive", then "my drive" and then select save "newfile.txt".

But I get a Toast with "failed to save document". So this code is getting me there but not producing the file creation result I desire.

I checked that I do indeed get "RESULT_CANCELED" in onActivityResult.

The code snippet (given above) is essentially the same as that given in "create a new document" at  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

Anybody know why I cannot write this file into the cloud?
thanks.

Comment: What should be saved to that file? I see no content.

Comment: I also used CREATE_REQUEST_CODE in startActivityForResults with the same results. This is really more of a CREATE method.  I use a separate method for WRITE -ing in the contents into the created file. –